# Save null value with Spring repository to mongodb document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I want to save a null value to a document with a Spring Data Repository.

So someEntity below is an object with a property set to null in java.

```
...
repository.save(someEntity);
...
```

Spring will save this as undefined, meaning the property of the document is not set to null.
In our use case, we treat null as a proper value.

How can you solve this without overriding the save() method in the repository?

Comment: Also reaallly interesting in this!!!

Comment: `@Version` - Does your attribute have this annotation?

Comment: @BatScream - no... ...should it?
My colleague just made this after a dialogue with the Spring peeps: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1107

Comment: still not solved...