# Does Spring Data for MongoDB allow documents with optional fields?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Can I have a nullable field that:
- if its value is null, we wouldn't store the field (name or value) on the document, and 
- if its value is non-null, we would store the field name and value on it.

Comment: That's how MongoDB stores data.

Comment: Ah this is the default.  I imagined the nulls would get stored, but it seems the OPPOSITE (allowing/setting a null value) is a question that others are interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187749/save-null-value-with-spring-repository-to-mongodb-document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does, just do not set the property while creating the model and that field and the value will not be inserted in mongodb document. The fields for which the values are set, only those will be stored in the mongodb document.

```
package org.scalar.test;

import org.scalar.model.Product;
import org.scalar.model.Summary;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml");

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setId(String.valueOf(i));
                /*Summary summary = new Summary(); */

                MongoTemplate template = (MongoTemplate)context.getBean("mongoTemplate");

                template.save(product);

        }       

        System.out.println("end");
        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)context).close();


    }

}
```

Product.java

```
package org.scalar.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    public String id;
    public Summary summary;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Summary getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }
    public void setSummary(Summary summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }


}
```

Mongodb output

```
> db.products.find();
{ "_id" : "0", "_class" : "org.scalar.model.Product" }
{ "_id" : "1", "_class" : "org.scalar.model.Product" }
{ "_id" : "2", "_class" : "org.scalar.model.Product" }
{ "_id" : "3", "_class" : "org.scalar.model.Product" }
{ "_id" : "4", "_class" : "org.scalar.model.Product" }
{ "_id" : "5", "_class" : "org.scalar.model.Product" }
{ "_id" : "6", "_class" : "org.scalar.model.Product" }
{ "_id" : "7", "_class" : "org.scalar.model.Product" }
{ "_id" : "8", "_class" : "org.scalar.model.Product" }
{ "_id" : "9", "_class" : "org.scalar.model.Product" }
```

HTH